# How can I order entries by title when each title is numeric?

Tags: sorting, templating

*[I originally asked this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882510/craft-order-by-title-that-is-a-number), but I'm hoping for more response here.*

In Craft, I'm trying to order entries by the title. Each title is a number, but the sort function handles it like a string. Because of that `100` shows up before `2`, `31` before `4`, and so on.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').order('title').find() %}
    <h2>§{{entry.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to do this without extending  twig?

Comment: I see that you've ask this question before, over on main stackoverflow. Did you try the answer there using **natsort**?  [Question with natsort answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882510/craft-order-by-title-that-is-a-number)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my question I originally asked this on stack overflow. I would like to know is if there is a way to do this without extending twig.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that using MySQL’s [cast() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

```
craft.entries.section('mySection').order('cast(title as unsigned)')
```

Alternatively, you might get better performance if you create an actual Number field called “numberTitle”, attach it to your Entry Type, and set the Entry Type’s title to be [dynamically generated](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles) using the template “`{numberTitle}`”. Then you can just order by that field instead:

```
craft.entries.section('mySection').order('numberTitle')
```

Comment: That 2nd technique is interesting, but where exactly do you set that template for the title field? Can I set templates for other fields too?

Comment: See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles

Comment: Amazing answer. Just watch out if you're ordering by a custom field you need to put `field_` in front of the field handle. Eg: `craft.entries().section('mySection').orderBy('cast(field_customFieldHandle as unsigned)')` (Also use `orderBy` instead of `order` in Craft 3)

Answer (score 4):

Twig doesn't have a `natsort()` filter.

But I've put together a simple plugin which extends the sort-filter:

https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort